# Error while running react-native cli project when i trying to run it on emulator then it throw error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ubuntu, expo

~/Desktop/React_NProject/ExpoMobileApp$ npx react-native run-android
info Starting JS server...

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'ExpoMobileApp'.

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
> Required by:
> project :
> > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.1' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin.
> Required by:
> project :
> > No matching variant of project :gradle-plugin was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.1' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Variant 'mainSourceElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Variant 'testResultsElementsForTest' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
error Failed to install the app.

i tried to clean gradlew but when i am trying to do that then it throw error

/Desktop/React_NProject/ExpoMobileApp/android$ ./gradlew clean

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'ExpoMobileApp'.

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
> Required by:
> project :
> > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.1' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin.
> Required by:
> project :
> > No matching variant of project :gradle-plugin was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.1' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Variant 'mainSourceElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Variant 'testResultsElementsForTest' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

Comment: as i can see is an enviroment miss configuration, like is written in you error : 

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

Take a look in youtube, you'll find a lot of tutorial to setup or environment or the official documentation:  https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am also facing similar issue

This is how i am using currently
Open the android folder in android studios of the project and run the project from android studios

[image: Run from here]

After running the project
[image: You will this kind of error]

Then open project in VS code and from terminal

```
 npx react-native start
```

Then reload in emulator so that your project will start running

Comment: i am using vscode for devlopment having android studio only for android emulator but when i run npx react-native run-android after that i get error like gradle version n all but i dont understand when i am creating project in my local with all project structure which is by default added by npx when i run npx react-native init <name> then how its version should be different coz all dependencies is added by default by npx itself can you help me why it showing like that i am new to react native

Comment: why this error when npx itself add all dependencies and file structure itself to latest   then how to solve Could not determine the dependencies of null. Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'. > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2. Required by: project : > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found.

Comment: and also when i try to run npx react-native doctor then its  is ok but why it doesnot get path for android studio ================     ✖ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
 ✓ Gradlew - Build tool required for Android builds
 ✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android